# State and Country picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]In lead object I have State and Country picklist and I need to create a custom VF page to display only few fields. I used the tag . Country__c is a formula field for type text (Country__c = Country). My problem is that when i giv ethe apex:inputfiled tag its not displaying any picklist in the vf page. I need help in fixing this issue.

Thanks
IRaj

Comment: **Country__c is a formula field for type text (Country__c = Country)** I don't understand what you are trying to say here.  Are you trying to display a formula field as a picklist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've enabled State and Country picklists and want the picklist values to be displayed, the field name you want to use should look more like `country_code`. A formula field should be read only. It won't display a picklist. Instead, it processes the formula it's based on which could possibly be a cross-object formula field of some kind. In any case, it's not something that would be editable.

Comment: Hi @crmprogdev, yes it worked no underscores its "countrycode" (<apex:inputfield value="{!Lead.Countrycode}"/>) Thanks for ur help :)